# The use of prepositions in one sentence. (Incorporate xxx into xxx as xxx)

Tags: prepositions, sentence, syntactic-analysis, ambiguity

I recently wrote a social science paper, and the title I want to use is "Incorporating Fairness into Contracts as Boundaries" The question is, the part "contracts as boundaries" is a title of another paper which I improved on, but I feel bad to use quotation marks like "Incorporating Fairness into 'Contracts as Boundaries'" or to use "Incorporating Fairness into Boundary Contracts"(Or maybe this is a good idea?).

However, "Incorporating Fairness into Contracts as Boundaries" sounds like
I am trying to incorporate fairness into contracts, and this "fairness"  works as "boundaries" instead of the meaning I intended. So, can you give me some clues about how to resolve this problem? Or, maybe I have some misunderstanding about this title(e.g., It is actually fine to use the original title without causing ambiguity.) Please help.

Comment: I don’t understand your “I feel bad to use quotation marks” why would you feel bad about that?

Comment: Sorry I didn't explain, because my work is not entirely built on the original work, so a quotation mark seems to be over-emphasizing that my work is purely an extension.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Incorporating Fairness into "Contracts as Boundaries"**

What does your style book say? I don't have a direct link to *The Chicago Manual of Style (CMS)* but [*GranmarBooks.com*](http://data.grammarbook.com/blog/quotation-marks/titles-of-books-plays-articles-etc-underline-italicize-use-quotation-marks/) explains what CMS says:

---

Titles of Books, Plays, Articles, etc.: Underline? Italics? Quotation Marks?

Prior to computers, people were taught to underline titles of books and plays and to surround chapters, articles, songs, and other shorter works in quotation marks. However, here is what *The Chicago Manual of Style* says: When quoted in text or listed in a bibliography, titles of books, journals, plays, and other freestanding works are italicized; titles of articles, chapters, and other shorter works are set in roman and enclosed in quotation marks.

---

It appears that "Contracts as Boundaries" is a title of a research paper  but not a published book, so I would follow the rules accordingly and use quotation marks around the title.

It also sounds like a technical term in your field of study, to me, and if that's the case, using quotation marks catches my eye, quite effectively.

So it won't be like, **Incorporating Fairness into *Reconstructing Contracts***, in which *Reconstructing Contracts* is a title of a book.

Comment: Thanks, it is indeed a title and also a technical term, so I'll use quotation marks